# Getting connection count on Linkedin in JSON or XML

Tags: xml, json, linkedin-api

Been scouring google for ages and I am having no luck finding what I'm looking for, or if it is even possible...

Does anyone know if it is possible to get your LinkedIn Connection count in either JSON or XML format?

For example:

Twitter: http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=williamclaxton
Feedburner: http://feedburner.google.com/api/awareness/1.0/GetFeedData?uri=WillClaxton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/num-connections
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/num-connections?format=json

Comment: I don't want to sound dumb, but I am going to... how do i actually get that to return the number of connections? as in, where do i put my username in that URL?

Comment: @Will Those are the endpoint URL's that will give you the info you need on the [LinkedIn API](https://developer.linkedin.com/apis). Basically, you authenticate against the API giving whatever code/script/site you need the connection count in access to connect to LinkedIn on your behalf, then you can make calls to the endpoints mentioned and get the data you need.

Comment: @Will you cannot look up information anonymously using the LinkedIn API. You need to use OAuth to generate credential for a user (yourself?) and then pass that information to LinkedIn.

Comment: Note that this will cap at 500. The quickest way I've found of finding the actual number is to do `/people/~:(connections:())` which returns an empty `<person></person>` for each connection but does give you the correct count.

Comment: @enashnash The result when querying for connections has a "total" field that shows the total number of connections

Comment: Last time I used it, which was a while ago, it wouldn't return a total greater than 500. No idea if it's changed.